# JMX parameters correctly passed but couldn't connect using jconsole

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

i have passed following jmx parameters in a java program and deployed it on some remote machine.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5001 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Still when I am trying to connect to the host using host:port in jconsole, it redirects me to InsecureConnection and then it doesn't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=<hostname>  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<pornNum>
```

---

When you only specify `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port` it binds rmi registry to that port. This registry contains remote object, and you should add `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` to specify where to bind that remote object.
Otherwise random port will be used and it will be not good if you have firewall.
You can see `sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap#startRemoteConnectorServer` for more details